# Return subtype as supertype java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

If I have the following code

```
public class Can
{
    ...
    public Can makeCan(String cont)
    {   boolean winner = false;
        Can a;
        if(turn)
        {   winner = true;
            a = new PromotionCan(cont,winner);  
        }
        else
        {   a = new Can(cont);
        }
        return a;
    }
    ...
}
```

First is this even possible because it compiles fine. But I can't perform operations using a method in `PromotionalCan`:

```
public class PromotionCan extends Can
{
    ...
    public boolean isWinner() throws NotEmptyCanException
    if(win)
       {    System.out.println("Can is winner");
           return win;
        }
        else
        {   System.out.println("Can is not winner");
            return win;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Does `makeCan` not return both `Can` and `PromotionalCan`? If so, how can I operate on a variable when `PromotionalCan` is returned? Thanks.

Edit:
`PromotionalCan` inherits from `Can` and the second method is in `PromotionalCan`

Comment: I took out the part  of the method which uses the exception, I don't think it wouldve been helpful

Comment: You need to provide some information about your class structure.  What are Can and PromotionalCan?  What is "win" in the second method?

Comment: PromotionalCan is a subtype of Can, and win is basically used to output a statement

Answer (score 2):

makeCan will only ever return a Can because that is it's return type as seen in this line:

```
public Can makeCan(String cont)
```

I'm assuming that PromotionalCan is a subtype of Can, but my first statement still stands-- makeCan will only ever return an object of type Can.

Comment: So, even if a PromotionalCan is returned, only Can methods can be used?

Comment: No, you will have to cast the return to `PromotionalCan` to use the functions in that `class`, as long as your are sure a `PromotionalCan` was returned.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Its just my specification requires me to return Can when one condition is true, and a PromotionalCan when the condition is false. IS casting the returned Can the only way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the best way, but it is certainly one way. Alternatively, you could move the `isWinner` function to the `Can` class, and then you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: @MichaelPickett I can't do that either, if there is no other way I will probably cast, thank you for helping

Comment: No problem. You can cast more easily by checking the class of the object returned, i.e. `System.out.println(returnedObj.class.toSimpleName());` or something similar. Even though you returned a `Can` object, the class of the object should still be `PromotionalCan` thats what was returned.